# Why is the Service Unavailable Error using Lapply?

Tags: r, spotify

I am using the spotifyr library where I want to find audio features for multiple tracks. For example I can do this in order to find the audio features of a specific song using it's id.

```
analysis2 <- get_track_audio_features("2xLMifQCjDGFmkHkpNLD9h", 
                                 authorization = get_spotify_access_token())
```

Yesterday, I wrote this function below that takes all the tracks in a dataframe and finds the audio features for all of them and stores them in a list and it was working fine.

```
get_analysis <- function(track_id)
{
  analysis <- get_track_audio_features(track_id, 
                                       authorization = get_spotify_access_token())  
}

tracks_list <- lapply(all_tracks$track.id, get_analysis)
```

Now I am getting an error saying Request failed [503] and  Error in get_track_audio_features(track_id, authorization = get_spotify_access_token()) : Service Unavailable (HTTP 503).

I am still able to find the audio features of a specific song so I am not sure which service is unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are reaching a song in your data for which the response is denied from spotify. You could try adding an error-catching mechanism to see which one it is:

```
get_analysis <- function(track_id){
 tryCatch(
  expr = {
   get_track_audio_features(track_id, authorization = get_spotify_access_token())
 }, 
  error = function(e){
   print(track_id)
 }) -> analysis
 return(analysis)
}

tracks_list <- lapply(all_tracks$track.id, get_analysis)
```

I looked at the source code for the package and didn't see any sneaky rate-limiting issues and the Web API page shows error 503 as a generic error that needs waiting to be resolved (https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/). Thus you could also try just adding a 10 minute wait (I couldn't find how long exactly it is on Spotify's website):

```
get_analysis <- function(track_id){
 tryCatch(
  expr = {
   get_track_audio_features(track_id, authorization = get_spotify_access_token()) -> output
 return(output)
 }, 
  error = function(e){
   print(track_id)
   return(e)
 }) -> output
}

wait.function <- funciton(){
 Sys.sleep(600)
}

get_analysis_master <- function(all_tracks){
 k <- 1
 tracks_list <- list()
 for(track.id in all_tracks$track.id){
  get_analysis(track.id) -> output
  if(!inherits(output, "error")){
   tracks_list[[k]] <- output
   k <- k + 1
   } else {
    wait.function()
   }
 return(tracks_list)
 }
  
get_analysis_master(all_tracks) -> tracks_list
```